# C++ Memory De-allocation in Large Lists with Threads on Fedora 35

Tags: c++, multithreading, heap-memory

I am experiencing an issue related to memory management in C++ on a Fedora 35 system with 8GB of memory. Specifically, I am working with two threads where each thread is supposed to allocate approximately 4GB of memory, use it, and then deallocate it. The threads are controlled with a `std::mutex` to ensure that only one thread is allocating or deallocating memory at a time.

Here is the code I am working with:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;

// Function for first thread
void manageList1() {
    mtx.lock();
    {
        std::list<std::string> myList1;

        for(int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
            myList1.push_back(std::string(80000, 'a')); // Approx. 4GB
        }

        myList1.clear(); // Clear list
    }
    mtx.unlock();

    while(true){} // Keep thread 1 from exiting
}

// Function for second thread
void manageList2() {
    mtx.lock();
    {
        std::list<std::string> myList2;
        for(int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
            myList2.push_back(std::string(80000, 'a')); // Approx. 4GB
        }

        myList2.clear(); // Clear list
    }
    mtx.unlock();
}

int main() {
    std::thread listThread1(manageList1);
    std::thread listThread2(manageList2);

    // Don't join listThread1
    listThread2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the total memory usage of this program to not exceed approximately 4GB (plus the overhead for the program and threads) since one thread should free its memory before the other begins allocating. However, what I observe is that the memory usage gradually increases until the system runs out of memory and kills the process.

I am aware that in C++, memory that is freed is not necessarily immediately returned to the operating system, and it might be kept around for future allocations by the same program. However, in this case, it seems like the memory from the first thread isn't being reused by the second thread, which leads to excessive memory usage.

I would appreciate any insights into this problem. Why is the memory not being freed as expected? Is there a way to ensure the memory is freed immediately after it's no longer needed?

Comment: Are you sure the second thread is unlocked at all?

Comment: Obviously, this is some kind of an experiment, but what is it intended to prove? You have three threads (including the main thread), but you never allow any two of them to do anything interesting at the same time. What is the point of that?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Presumably this should prove that destructing `std::list` deallocates its memory.

Comment: `while(true){}` causes undefined behavior. Infinite loops like this are not allowed. Also, you never join the thread, which, if it wasn't UB already, would cause the program to exit with a call to `std::terminate`.

Comment: This looks like it might be ~4G that you can see, but you're allocating it in smaller chunks,and each chunk will have overhead the memory management system needs for its own book-keeping. `std::list` is almost always a doubly linked list, so every node in the `list` will have `prev` and `next` pointers for even more overhead.

Comment: Side note: In a way, you're lucky. Since the program describes no observable behaviour, it doesn't do anything, the compiler is allowed to optimize the whole thing out, effectively producing `int main(){}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, fair enough, but even if it "deallocates" the memory, that's no guarantee that the next allocation won't allocate new pages from the OS... Especially not if the next allocation happens in a different thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If this is indeed a per-thread heap issue, proving that would make an interesting answer.

Comment: Side note: You have no guarantee that `manageList1` acquires the mutex before `manageList2`. Shouldn't matter with the problem you're dealing with, but sooner or later it will. Thread 2 could grab the mutex, complete first, and the program could exit before thread 1 gets a chance to start rolling.

Comment: @user4581301 Even if this is allocation overhead, there's only 50k elements. How much overhead do you need to hit +4GB...

Comment: A lot. And with virtual memory almost certainly in play it should be really hard to run the program out of memory.

Comment: The program is fundamentally flawed anyway.  `mtx.lock();` if the `push_back` throws an exception, you have a forever-locked mutex.  Use `std::lock_guard` instead.

Comment: OP, how do you compile your code? Might it be 32-bit or debug application?

Comment: I'm able to repro this on Ubuntu 22.04 with [this code](https://pastebin.com/wexWv4jP), which should be UB-free (removed infinite loop and added missing `.join()`). The program sits at 7.5 GB mem usage. `g++` 11.3 as a compiler, with no flags.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "no flags": It requires at least `-pthread`

Comment: @user17732522 Ubuntu's GCC seems to add it by default.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Does this still happen if you set the `MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_` environment variable to something like 65536 or below when calling the program?

Comment: @user17732522 Doesn't happen with `MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_=65536`. I'm now seeing the same sawtooth graph as the answerer below (at least if I slow down the loops with some sleeps).

Comment: @user17732522 Do you know why this affects things?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The explanation is probably somewhere in https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals combined with the order of allocations and deallocations performed by the program.

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting, will look into it. I thought fragmentation can only be causing by having (small) fragments currently allocated, but this code should free all of them, hmm.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't really know how exactly glibc's malloc implementation works, but the docs say "_If the chunk is large enough, coalesce any fastbins and see if the top chunk is large enough to give some memory back to the system. Note that this step might be deferred, for performance reasons, and happen during a malloc or other call._" and combined with there possibly being different arenas assigned to the threads, maybe releasing the memory is just being deferred for too long. Anyhow, if `MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_` is smaller than the strings, `mmap` is used and always released on `free`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What happens if you add [`malloc_trim(0)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) after `}` but before releasing the lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments, this is my best guess:

You are using glibc's `malloc` implementation which is where memory allocation requests for your strings ultimately end up. (glibc is the most common provider of the C standard library implementation on Linux distributions, but there are others like musl)

The behavior you are seeing is a side effect of how this particular `malloc` is implemented. In particular, it doesn't consider `80000` bytes large enough to allocate and deallocate memory for each string completely separately using `mmap`. The default limit for that is 128k and can be set in code (using [`mallopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) which is non-portable) as well as with the environment variable `MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_`.

So, the usual chunk-based arena allocator that is used for all smaller allocations is used. By default `malloc` will use multiple arenas up to some upper limit and try to assign different threads different arenas so their allocations don't interfere.

Also, the `malloc` implementation delays releasing back the free memory at the top of a heap used by an arena after a `free` until a later point, e.g. a call to `malloc`, in order to avoid releasing and then immediately reacquiring memory and maybe also to keep `free` as fast as possible.

So, it seems likely that after the closing `}` in your thread, the list has been completely deallocated by calls to glibc's `free`, but `free` decided to not yet release the memory back to the system.

Because the other thread then operates in its own arena using its own heap, it will also not release the first thread's memory back to the operating system and you end up with needed double the amount of memory that you expected.

You can force the `malloc` implementation to release all memory back to the operating system after the `}` with a call to [`malloc_trim(0)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html). Of course that is non-portable and will only work on systems using glibc or a compatible alternative.

---

I don't know much about glibc's `malloc` implementation, so there might be wrong points in the explanation above. An overview of the implementation can be found at https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is given to you in comments, you're deeply in undefined behavior territory. However, if it helps any, in MSVC the program behaves as you'd expect:

[image]

And then of course it crashes with a `std::terminate` because you don't join or detach the first thread.

Comment: Are you saying that `while(true) {}` and lack of `.join()` is what causes the infinite memory usage? I don't buy it. I would tell OP to try again with those changes to confirm.

Comment: I'm saying that there is no infinite memory usage in MSVC.

Comment: Then the issue is compiler-specific? I think this should be a comment.

Comment: Also just to be clear, I don't believe OP at face value without seeing a memory graph that shows this infinite memory allocation thing. And even if I did, I wouldn't believe the result is linked to his code without further proof. The above is concrete evidence that his description isn't true in Windows with MSVC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Might just be that the infinite loop is the problem if they are using Clang. On godbolt with Clang and `-O2` it variably exits with `std::terminate`, aborts with an invalid `free()` diagnostic or just a quiet segault depending on exact numbers used.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496809/c-memory-de-allocation-in-large-lists-with-threads-on-fedora-35#comment134879636_76496809

Comment: That is so weird, I get the exact same graph with that code as well. So it has to be compiler or system specific then, right? Is GCC's STL broken?

Comment: @Blindy Testing a program with UB means that we can't trust the results - good or bad.

Comment: @RichardCritten I was trying to simulate a part of my QT project in a simple code. I first saw this happen in a scenario with a Qthread that's intended to work without exiting after clearing a QList of QStrings. no UB there but this still happens in Ubuntu and Fedora distros with gcc but it works in Windows with MSVC.

Comment: @RichardCritten, Cat's code doesn't have UB and still doesn't deallocate properly. Honestly, at this point I'd post this on GCC's issue forum. Also, Mehdi, the distro doesn't matter for this, only the OS (Linux), compiler (gcc) and STL (I'm assuming you're all using the standard GNU STL).

Comment: @Blindy It is probably not the compiler or STL implementation but a detail in the behavior of the system libc's `malloc` implementation, which varies with Linux distribution, but most use glibc. And the behavior might be intentional, optimized for a different use case. See the comments under the question.